# How to execute filtered Get-ADUser using Access VBA

Tags: vba, powershell, shell, ms-access

My team is tasked with scrubbing medical application user accounts for pending scheduled termination, and if necessary, email the users to avoid possible problems. However, the medical application email records are frequently incorrect.

I'm creating a MS Access tool for my peers who aren't as comfortable with PowerShell, which is what I would normally use to process the user account list and dig up emails.

Having difficulties with a VBA shell() function to run a filtered Get-ADUser command. Below is what I have so far:

```html
Dim runPwsh As String, getADemail As String, Surname As String, Givenname As String, pwshGetADEmail As String

'In production, Surname and GivenName will be variables from a form txtbox string
Surname = "Smith"
Givenname = "John"

getADemail = "Get-ADUser -filter " & """""""Surname -eq '" & Surname & "'" & " -and GivenName -like '" & Givenname & "*'"""""" -Property EmailAddress | %{$_.EmailAddress}"

pwshGetADEmail = "Powershell -Command """ & getADemail & """"

Debug.Print pwshGetADEmail
runPwsh = Shell(pwshGetADEmail, vbHide)
```

The shell() function command should look like:

```
Powershell -Command "Get-ADUser -filter """Surname -eq 'Smith' -and GivenName -like 'John*'""" -Property EmailAddress | %{$_.EmailAddress}"
```

If executed from command prompt, the command returns valid results.

However, from Access, I get error **"Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure or Argument."**

I've spent several hours on this already, but I cant figure out what I'm missing.

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not escaping the enclosed double quotes correctly. Eliminate one from the three - use "" instead of """. Have you tried to dump the command string to a debug window and then copy/paste into command window? That will give you the real error with your syntax

Comment: @dbmitch Thanks for the input. However, it seems my organization's McAfee HIPS software is preventing me from running VBA Shell+PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my organization's McAfee HIPS software installed on all workstations prevents MS Office applications from running VBA Shell() function with PowerShell commands, generating the **Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure or Argument.** error.

The syntax is correct. I confirmed this by executing on a virtual host machine without the HIPS software.

```
Dim runPwsh As String, getADemail As String, Surname As String, Givenname As String, pwshGetADEmail As String

Surname = Me.txtSurname
Givenname = Me.txtFirstname

getADemail = "Get-ADUser -filter " & """""""Surname -eq '" & Surname & "'" & " -and GivenName -like '" & Givenname & "*'"""""" -Property EmailAddress | %{$_.EmailAddress}"

pwshGetADEmail = "Powershell -Command """ & getADemail & """"

runPwsh = Shell(pwshGetADEmail, vbHide)
```

It seems I will need to find a different approach.

Update: 20APR2022

Was able to get it working. Essentially, since the HIPS software allows Shell(cmd.exe) but not Shell(powershell.exe), I thought of trying something like:

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /c " powershell.exe -comment "Get-ADUser" "")
```

And it worked!
My VBA code below:

Sub for running PowerShell with SQL to update my table using array of collected Active Directory properties:

```
Sub GetADInformation(argFullName As String)

DoEmptyClipboard = Shell("cmd.exe /c echo off | clip")

'Split argFullName with comma as delimeter
strFullName = Split(argFullName, ",")
strSurname = strFullName(0) 'AD: Surname
strGivenname = strFullName(1) 'AD: GivenName

'Build Get-ADUser command
strGetADUser = "Get-ADUser -filter " & """""" & _
"""Surname -eq '" & strSurname & "'" & _
" -and GivenName -like '" & strGivenname & "*'""""" & _
""" -Property SamAccountName,Division,EmailAddress,DistinguishedName | " & _
"%{$_.SamAccountName,$_.Division,$_.EmailAddress,$_.DistinguishedName}"

'Wrap Get-ADUser command within Command Prompt Powershell.exe with -Command parameter
'Results will be piped to clipboard
strPwsh = "Powershell -Command """ & strGetADUser & """| Clip"

'Use Shell() to run command prompt command
DoRunPwsh = Shell("CMD /C " & strPwsh, vbNormal)

'Wait 3-5 seconds for command to finish
Call WaitFor(5)

'Collect results from clipboard
ADarray = Clipboard_GetText()

'Visual Basic Carriage Return Line Feed (vbCrLf)
'Split ADArray with 'carriage return line feed' as delimiter
userADinfo = Split(ADarray, vbCrLf)

'Build SQL
strSQLupdate = "UPDATE tblUser SET " & _
    "ADemail='" & userADinfo(2) & _
    "', ADname='" & userADinfo(0) & _
    "', ADdivision='" & userADinfo(1) & _
    "', ADdistinguishedname='" & userADinfo(3) & _
    "' WHERE FullName='" & argFullName & "';"
    
DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLupdate

DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)

End Sub
```

I called the sub with a button click from the main form.

```
Private Sub btnGetAD_Click()

'exampleFullName = "Last,First M"

GetADInformation (exampleFullName)

End Sub
```

Function to collect text from clipboard

```
Public Function Clipboard_GetText() As String
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

StatusBar ("Extracting text from Clipboard...")

    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .GetFromClipboard
        Clipboard_GetText = .GetText
    End With
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: Clipboard_GetText" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
    
End Function
```

Sub for delaying time

```
Sub WaitFor(NumOfSeconds As Long)

Dim SngSec As Long
'VBA Timer function returns a Single(datatype) representing the number of seconds elapsed since midnight.

SngSec = Timer + NumOfSeconds

Do While Timer < SngSec

DoEvents

TimeRemaining = Abs(Timer - SngSec)

sTimeRemaining = "Time Remaining " & TimeRemaining & " Seconds"

StatusBar (sTimeRemaining)

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).